# Is possible to use material autocomplete as an independent component?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'd like to use the same material autocomplete in multiple parts of my project. It's getting annoying to repeat the code and it's not maintainable. Mostly use this material component using reactive forms, but my project has a template-driven form approach. The input use a template reference to link with the autocomplete, but I do not know how this can be known from a child component instead being in the same template.

```
 <input [(ngModel)]="text" [matAutocomplete]="auto" (ngModelChange)="filterProducts(text)"  />

        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">                   
            <mat-option id="product_box" *ngFor="let product of searchResult['products']" (onSelectionChange)="searchProduct(product)" [value]="product.name">
               {{ product.name }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Just place all of this in your component.

Comment: @ritaj the problem is that the inputs have different behaviors. Such as different animations states, etc.

Comment: Another solution would be to create a directive and use ComponentFactoryResolver to dynamically create the mat-autocomplete component.

Comment: So just pass animations and states as inputs to your wrapper.